# PHP array merge keys

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP, is there any built-in array function that I could use to change an array...

From:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 2
        )

)
```

To:

```
Array
(
     [item_id] => Array ( [0] => 1, [1] => 2, [2] => 3 )
)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you cant find a built-in function, you can write a small loop. Although im sure this can also be done with `array_map`

```
foreach($yourArray as $subArray)
{
 $newArray["item_id"][]=$subArray["item_id"];
}
```